# Jquery not reading special characters from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement for creating a simple SMS validator that checks if * is the beginning symbol and # is the ending. The form has a text input field and a button Validate.

On click of the button..it prints the Data in the form and the first and last character. It's working well with all the characters except for # and &. Whenever I enter such a symbol... jquery excludes it. Not sure what is the workaround this.

[image]

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#transactionForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        var amountToSend = $("input#txnID").val();
    //alert(amountToSend);
    var length = $('input#txnID').val().length;

    if(length > 3){
        document.getElementById("loadingBlock").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("calculationBlock").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("errorBlock").style.display = 'none';   

        var url = '<?php echo API_URL ?>';
        url = url+'/v1/smsValidator.php?txnID='+amountToSend;

//Start of AJAX call    
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json', 
    url: url,
}).done(function(response) {
    document.getElementById("loadingBlock").style.display = 'none';
    var desc1 = $('#desc1');
    var messageTitle = $('#messageTitle');

    if(response.error){
        document.getElementById("errorBlock").style.display = 'block';
        $("#errorTitle").html(response.message);
    }else{
    document.getElementById("calculationBlock").style.display = 'block';
    $("#messageTitle").html(response.message);  
    }

});
//End of AJAX call
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Surely because you aren't escaping this special characters in `url`...  `url = url+'/v1/smsValidator.php?txnID='+encodeURIComponent(amountToSend);`.

Comment: How and because you are sending POST request, why don't you set this data in body request?  `$.ajax({data: amountToSend, ...});`

Comment: @Awolff ... Thanks...your answer worked for me. Can you post as answer so that it can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

1. You get the DOM element
2. You get it's value
3. You check if the first element is `*` and the last element is `#`

   ```
   var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
   // in jQuery it's something like: var inputText = $("#inputText).val()
   if (inputText[0] === "*" && inputText[inputText.length - 1] === "#") {
       // the number is valid 
   }
   ```

Comment: I am validating this server side...using php... but javascript is not sending data with & or #